# How to send broadcast UDP packet in swift? "To all clients"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, networking, iot

I faced up with a new issue in swift!
wanna send UDP packet from my app to all clients "so I wanna broadcast it".
When I run this code because I'm sending broadcast UDP I have an error.
Does any one know how to fix it?

```
import UIKit
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let data = "Hello".data(using: .utf8)
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "connection")
    var client = NWConnection(host: NWEndpoint.Host("192.168.43.255"), port: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: 4000), using: NWParameters.udp)
    
    
    func test()  {
        
        self.client.start(queue: queue)
        self.client.send(content: data, completion: .idempotent)

    }

    var buttonOnOff: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        buttonOnOff = UIButton(type: .system)
        buttonOnOff.setTitle("ON/OFF", for: .normal)
        buttonOnOff.backgroundColor = .black
        buttonOnOff.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(buttonOnOff)
        constraintsInit()
        buttonOnOff.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onOffTouched), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
 func constraintsInit() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            buttonOnOff.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            buttonOnOff.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)])
    }


   @objc func onOffTouched() {
        test()
    }
```

Comment: Who are your "clients"? What devices do you want to reach, over what network?

Comment: any devices which has UDP receiver.
for example over home wifi.
I came up with a code which is ok with sending UDP packets to a exact ip but when I change it for send broadcast then I have an error 
"nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke [C1:1] sendmsg(fd 4, 5 bytes) [13: Permission denied]"

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code and what happens.

Comment: I updated my question as u said